# JSCH Channel Shell, Input / Output

Tags: java, shell, netbeans, jsch

I am having some issues using JSCH and sending commands to shell.

I have a console GUI Window setup and system.out has been redirected to the TextArea and this works fine, however i am unable to input any commands

Here is the connect code for the session

```
    this.channel=session.openChannel("shell");

    PipedInputStream pip = new PipedInputStream(40);
    this.channel.setInputStream(pip);

    PipedOutputStream pop = new PipedOutputStream(pip);
    PrintStream print = new PrintStream(pop);

    this.channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

    print.println("ls"); 

    this.channel.connect(3*1000);
```

This works fine, and runs the ls command and displays the output, however if i now want to run more commands these dont work.

i have a TextBox setup and a "Send" button to send these commands to the server coded below.

```
    String send = jServerInput.getText();

    try {
        PipedInputStream pip = new PipedInputStream(40);
        //this.channel.setInputStream(pip);

        PipedOutputStream pop = new PipedOutputStream(pip);
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(pop);
        //this.channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        //System.out.println(send);
        print.println(send);
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
    }
```

However hitting the "Send" Button does nothing. I am clearly missing something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that i needed to declare PrintStream as a Private so

```
 private PrintStream print;
```

Then after i had created the initial PrintStream as

```
 print = new PrintStream(pop);
```

I was able to access it in other parts of the programme rather than create new ones, so all i needed in my send command in the end was

```
 String send = jServerInput.getText();
 print.println(send);
```